# AWS S3 policy to allow access to buckets ending with particular name

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Is it possible to write an AWS S3 policy such that

1. can read all objects in bucket which names ending in "archive" (the bucket name ending in archive, no constraint on object names)
2. can read-write all objects in buckets ending in "output"

Can that be done?

I can't find "conditions" that would allow me to do that...

Thanks

PS: 
1) I just edited the question because there was ambiguity as whether it was the bucket or the object name ending in "..."
2) I have since gathered that I can't filter the names of the buckets that can be listed
3) The comment from [bruno-reis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150339/bruno-reis) makes it clear that it would be a bad idea anyway

Comment: What *ends in "archive"/"output"*? Is it the objects that end in "archive"/"output"? Or is it the name of the *bucket* that has that suffix? The solution to your problem is quite different depending on your answer to this.

Comment: it is the end of the bucket name, not the objects

Comment: Make sure you edit your question to add that, then, because the question is unclear and the answer depends on it. In any case, it's usually not a good idea to have any dependencies or rules on bucket names. First, it's a namespace that you don't fully control, so a name that you might need may already be in use by someone else. Second, it's way too easy to make security mistakes leading to leaks: the exact thing you're trying to do (use a wildcard on a bucket name to allow or deny things) is something I've seen countless times at the root of security incidents. I'd strongly advise against that

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible.

You are asking for a policy that applies to multiple buckets. Therefore, this would need to be an **IAM Policy** because a Bucket Policy only applies to a specific bucket.

While IAM policies allow wildcards, they are pretty limited in their capability. For example, this policy would *appear* to work, and does indeed grant access to a bucket ending with `-output`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*-output/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, this command will succeed:

```
aws s3 cp foo-output/bar.txt .
```

However, it also allows this command:

```
aws s3 cp foo/results-output/bar.txt .
```

This is because the wildcards in the policy do not differentiate between the part of the ARN that refers to the **bucket name** and the **path/object name**.

So, it is possible that they can access a bucket that does *not* end in `-output`. Thus, it is an unsafe policy.